# Search data in a packet. In python

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, replace, byte

I'm trying to program a small HTTP local proxy server to run on my machine and run some tests.
My server currently runs perfectly and serves the requests fine.

However, when I try to analyse the packer - I get a problem.

I'm searching for the tag "" in my packets, and print a message to a log when I find it.
It works on a very limited number of websites, while on the other, like StackOverflow for example, it doesn't.

Do I need to some sort of decoding before I search for the word in the received data? If so - which decoding? How do I recode the data to serve to the browser?

Here's my code for the searching and replacing:

```
data = i.recv(8192)
   if data:
      if "<head>" in data:
         print "Found Head Tag."
```

The above code is a simple python code to retrieve the data from the socket, save it to the data object, and search for the wanted tag. As I said, it works on very few websites, and not on the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many webservers use compression to lower bandwidth usage.
You will need to check HTTP headers for Content-Encoding and apply the required operations (i.e. gzip decompression) to get the plain text.

Comment: Thanks! But, how can I decompress a data chunk, as the above one? When I try using the zlib module, I get an error, saying that it is not a valid compressed data. I'd be happy if you helped me solving it. Do I need to buffer the whole responsone? It'd slow the surfing drastically, won't it?

Comment: Also, will it matter if I used zlib instead of gzip? Tvm!

Comment: Yes, you will need to buffer the whole HTTP response, check the value of Content-Encoding, extract response's body (no headers) and pass it to "gzip" module (the compression algorithm used by zlib is the same, but their output formats are not compatible). Of course the response could be compressed or encoded using different algorithms, but, afaik, only gzip is actually used. You should also consider to re-compress data after mangling or remove the Content-Encoding header before forward result to your client.